# Parsing Map with null value in Typescript from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I am using the following class in Typescript to parse Employee data received as JSON using `TypedJson.parse()`

```
@JsonObject()
export class Employee { 

    @JsonMember()
    public name: string;

    @JsonMember()
    public columns: { [name: string]: any };
}
```

`columns` is a `Map<String, Object>` sent from Spring backend.

While parsing TypedJson ignores all the keys with value as `null` and thus no key values pair objects of the form `myKey: null` are created. I do not have options of replacing all `null` with `''`

How to get those null values parsed to objects with `null` values?

Comment: Do you have `myKey` declared as a `@JsonMember` of `Employee`?

Comment: No, I was assuming to be derived on the fly like Columns could have values like 
`car: Toyota, house: appartment`

Comment: You may want to try declaring them all. I'm not familiar with TypedJson, but I assume it tries to infer types from JSON properties and probably fails gracefully on props with `null` values. So, to account for these, you might need to declare them explicitly.

Comment: I do not know the count or the type on incoming object, so it will not be possible to declare it. My current code works correctly for non null values. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If this is the case, you may need to avoid using TypedJson and instead use a simple JSON.parse with an explicit `any`.

Comment: Hi @JonnyAsmar JSON.parse is giving same results. Any idea if the map definition for Json member can be defined in any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JonnyAsmar suggested JSON.parse works for this scenario.

I was previously doing

```
this._http.get(`${HTTP_URL}/${params.EmployeeId}/EmployeeData`, { params: params })
      .map(response => TypedJSON.parse(response.text(), Employee)
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

as a workaround I am now doing:

```
this._http.get(`${HTTP_URL}/${params.EmployeeId}/EmployeeData`, { params: params })
      .map(response => {
        let obj:JSON = JSON.parse(response.text());
        return obj;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I've seen the code of TypedJson - in current version 0.1.7 it is bug, but in the repository this bug is fixed, but not published yet.

So you can use workaround until next release just adding `= null!` as property default value:

```
    @JsonObject()
    export class Employee { 

        @JsonMember()
        public name: string = null!;

        @JsonMember()
        public columns: { [name: string]: any } = null!;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @cevek, I am afraid that is not working for me. I may not have explained my problem correctly. I have few value expected in columns which will be key value pairs like `{'car' : 'Toyota'}, { 'house': 'Appartment' },{ 'phone': null }`. Now when I try to parse `{'phone':null}` gets ignored. Any ideas ?